# Аппроксимация функции нескольких переменных

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

Для нахождения приближающей функции y = f(x) по методу наименьших квадратов и построения графиков я использовал следующие функции из пакета NumPy:

```
t = np.polyfit(x, y, 3)
f = np.poly1d(t)
ax.plot(x, f(x))
```

Теперь появилась необходимость найти коэффициенты и построить график для функции у которой несколько переменных y = f(x,z). Как можно решить данную задачу?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html#multivariate-interpolation

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html#id1

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо за ответы. Функций довольно много. Если Вы когда-нибудь сталкивались с похожей задачей, то какую использовали и что можете посоветовать?

Comment: лично мне не приходилось заниматься интерполяцией функций нескольких переменных. Но как всегда для того, чтобы понять какой метод вам больше подходит, надо понимать природу ваших данных. В худшем случае придется пробовать разные методы и сравнивать...

Comment: @MaxU Хорошо буду экспериментировать. Данные у меня следующие: Скорость движения определяемая гироскопом (зависимая переменная y), температурный коэффициент (первая независимая переменная x по которой строится функция), масштабный коэффициент (вторая независимая переменная z)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам нужна интерполяция или аппроксимация?

Интерполяция - это поиск значений между точками с известными значениями. На практике используют линейные приближения (в двумерном случае триангуляционные), либо кубические сплайны.

Аппроксимация - приближение неизвестной функции функцией из известного семейства. Семейство выбирают из каких-либо теоретических соображений.

Судя по вашему комментарию, вам нужна именно аппроксимация - подбор параметра по известной модели. Для аппроксимации в `scipy.optimize` есть функция [`curve_fit(f,x,y)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)

Она принимает на вход функцию вида `f(x, p1, p2, ..., pn)`, где x - переменная (возможно, многомерная),  `p1`, `p2`, ..., `pn` - параметры. `curve_fit` пытается подобрать параметры `p_i` так, чтобы минимизировать отклонения в заданных точках x от известных значений y.

Пример.

Подбор параметров для двумерной функции вида `r*cos(2*pi*r)` - три параметра: амплитуда A, сдвиг по оси x `dx` и сдвиг по оси y `dy`.

```
def r_cos(var_2d, A, dx, dy):
    x = var_2d[0] - dx
    y = var_2d[1] - dy
    r = np.sqrt(x*x + y*y)
    return A*r*np.cos(2*np.pi*r)
```

Для двумерности в переменную `var_2d` передается двумерный массив, где первая строка `x` а вторая строка `y`.

Тестовые данные - набор случайных 20 точек с небольшим шумом. Пареметры `A=1.5`, `dx=0.2`, `dy=0.3`.

```
vx = np.random.rand(20)
vy = np.random.rand(20)
v_2d = np.vstack((vx,vy))
Z = r_cos(v_2d, 1.5, 0.2, 0.3) + 0.05*np.random.rand(len(vx))
```

Подбор параметров:

```
p, p_cov = curve_fit(r_cos, v_2d, Z, p0=[1.0,0.0,0.0])
```

Возвращаемое значение `p` - оптимальный набор параметров, `p_cov` ковариционная матрица. Ошибка приближения i-го параметра оценивается как квадратный корень из соответствующего элемента на диагонали `p_cov`, вектор ошибок можно вычислить как `np.sqrt(np.diag(p_cov))`. Результат таков:
`[1.46694227, 0.19898437, 0.29632489] ± [0.01517198, 0.0016201 , 0.00238286]`

Comment: Да, Вы совершенно правы, мне нужна именно аппроксимация. Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ!

Comment: @leach удачи! Имейте в виду, во многих случах поиск аппроксимации - это вычислительно неустойчивая задача с большими градиентами. Кроме того, никогда нет гарантий что найден оптимальный набор параметров. `curve_fit` может застрять в локальном экстремуме. Чем ближе вы угадаете начальный набор параметров, тем лучше.